# Groovy transform two list into a Map [ Map<String,List<String>>]

Tags: groovy

I have two List

```
def listA = ['Yes','No','No','No','Yes','Yes']

def listB = ['option1','option2,'option3']
```

How can I transform this list into a map?  `Map<String, List<String>>` format

Eg

```
option1 : [Yes,No]
option2 : [No,No]
option3 :[Yes,Yes]
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use collate, transpose and collectEntries:

```
def listA = ['Yes','No','No','No','Yes','Yes']
def listB = ['option1','option2','option3']

def result = [listB, listA.collate(2)].transpose().collectEntries()
```

So we call `collate(2)` on `listA`.  This makes us a list like

```
[
    ['Yes', 'No'],
    ['No', 'No'],
    ['Yes', 'Yes']
]
```

We then add this to a list with `listB`, so we get:

```
[
    ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'],
    [
        ['Yes', 'No'],
        ['No', 'No'],
        ['Yes', 'Yes']
    ]
]
```

We can then call `transpose()`, which pairs up lists so we get

```
[
    ['option1', ['Yes', 'No']],
    ['option2', ['No', 'No']],
    ['option3', ['Yes', 'Yes']]
]
```

And finally, `collectEntries` takes these pairs, and converts them into map entries, with the first element being the key, and the second the value.

```
[
    option1:['Yes', 'No'],
    option2:['No', 'No'],
    option3:['Yes', 'Yes']
]
```

Which is the desired result